# How to specify "install --backup" in bjam

Tags: boost, bjam

I have a Jamfile with the following commands . I think bjam uses the unix `install` command to install. I'd like to change that to `install --backup` or `install -b` for a particular command.

```
exe datagen 
    : base_data_gen.cpp

install install-bin 
    : datagen 
    : <variant>release:<location>"$(BASETRADE_ROOT)_install/bin"
      <variant>debug:<location>"$(BASETRADE_ROOT)_install/bindebug"
    : release debug
    ;
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Build uses 'cp', in fact. This is not presently customizable, but you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org if you wish.